# Where is Arduino on Fedora?

Tags: arduino-ide, teensy, linux, fedora

I am trying to install the Teensy loader software but I need to know where Arduino is installed. Does anyone know where in Fedora the Arduino files are?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends how you installed it.

If you downloaded the tarball and extracted it then it's wherever you extracted it.

If you used a package manager to install it then they could be anywhere - you should look at the package manager software fedora uses (yum? it's been a while) to see how to find what files a package installs.

If you are running a modern version of Arduino (I know Debian based packages are from the stone age) then the board manager installs will be in `~/.arduino15`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have installed the tool from the Fedora repositories (that is, using yum/dnf or from the Software tool), the command to run the IDE will be installed at `/usr/bin/arduino` and you can run it from the command line just by typing `arduino` — or do the same in the search box in GNOME Shell.

Most of the package itself, including examples and libraries, will be installed under `/usr/share/arduino`.

And, once you run that program, it will create a new "sketchbook location" at `~/Arduino` — that is, a folder named "Arduino" in your home directory. If you've run the IDE already, that folder will already exist.